# Flutter Aligning label based on the previous Widget's width

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Good morning, I have a small issue about widget alignment.

I have a list of images of different sizes and I want to show them in a column with a small label under each one. The label must be aligned at the start based on its relative image.

The label uses the parent's constraints instead of the image's one, how could I constraint it based on the previous widget's width?

What I want to achieve:

[image: Goal]

What I get as result:

[image: Output]

Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Example extends StatelessWidget {
  const Example({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const List<Map<String, String>> images = [
      {
        'name': 'img1.jpg',
        'path': 'https://dummyimage.com/238x318/000/fff',
      },
      {
        'name': 'img2.jpg',
        'path': 'https://dummyimage.com/318x300/000/fff',
      },
      {
        'name': 'img3.jpg',
        'path': 'https://dummyimage.com/195x258/000/fff',
      },
      {
        'name': 'img4.jpg',
        'path': 'https://dummyimage.com/336x317/000/fff',
      },
    ];

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Example'),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          horizontal: 8.0,
        ),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: ListView(
                children: images
                    .map((imageItem) => Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Image.network(
                              imageItem['path']!,
                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              width: double.infinity,
                              child: Text(
                                imageItem['name']!,
                                textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ))
                    .toList(),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove  width from `SizedBox` and use  `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,` on Column widget.

```dart
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: const Text('Example'),
  ),
  body: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
      horizontal: 8.0,
    ),
    child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          child: ListView(
            children: images
                .map((imageItem) => Center(
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,// add this, default is center
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Image.network(
                            imageItem['path']!,
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          ),
                          SizedBox( // you can remove this 
                            child: Text(
                              imageItem['name']!,
                              textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ))
                .toList(),
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: Good morning, thanks for the solution but I would know why do we need the Center Widget to make it work? It seems Center widgets force new constraints based on their actual child's size.

Comment: In flutter  `Constraints go down. Sizes go up. Parent sets position.` The center widget is position the Column, you can  find more [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout/constraints)